# Difference between Quantum Mechanics and Quantum Computing

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation

Currently I'm reading Wolfgang Scherer's *Mathematics of Quantum Computing, An Introduction*.

I am really enjoying this book as it treats the subject from a mathematical point of view, which for me is helpful since it lets me understand how complicated physical questions link back to the mathematics I'm used to. For some context, I am a studying pure mathematics and going into fourth year, so have a background on real analysis, group theory, ring theory, metric spaces, topology and linear algebra to name a few.

Right now I'm at the point where he introduces the postulates used in Quantum Mechanics, and having compared to online materials, I find it hard to understand the link between his definitions, and what I've found online. Here is how he phrases the first postulate:

> **Postulate 1**, (*Observables and Pure states*): *An **observable**, that is, a physically measurable quantity of a quantum system is represented by a self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $\mathbb{H}$. If the preparation of a statistical ensemble is such that for any observable represented by its self-adjoint operator A the mean value of the observable can be calculated with the help of a vector $\vert \psi\rangle \in \mathbb{H}$ satisfying $\vert\vert\psi\vert\vert=1$ $$\langle A\rangle_{\psi}:=\langle\psi\vert A\psi\rangle$$ then the preparation is said to dscribe a **pure state** represented by the vector $\vert \psi\rangle \in \mathbb{H}$. One calls $\vert \psi\rangle$ the **state vector** or simply the state, and $\langle A\rangle_{\psi}$ is alled the (quantum mechanical) **expectation value** of the observable A in the pure state $\vert\psi\rangle$. The space $\mathbb{H}$ is said to be the HILBERT space of the quantum system.*

Compare this to a definition for the first postulate found [here](https://www.sydney.edu.au/science/chemistry/%7Emjtj/CHEM3117/Resources/postulates.pdf), for example:

> **Postulate 1**:
> The state of a quantum mechanical system is completely specified by the function $\psi(\mathbf{r},t)$ that depends on the coordinates of the particle, $\mathbf{r}$  and the time $t$. This function is called the wavefunction or state function and has the property that $\psi^{*}(\mathbf{r}, t)\psi(\mathbf{r},t)d\tau$ is the probability that the particle lies in the volume element $d\tau$ located at $\mathbf{r}$ and time $t$.

I am not including the full postulate, but they go on to describe the normalisation condition as an integral over $\mathbb{R}$ of $\psi^{*}(\mathbf{r}, t)\psi(\mathbf{r},t)$, which evaluates to $1$.

I have to clarify that, in his book, Scherer only uses finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces, whereas in classical QM, I am to understand that infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces are employed instead.

My questions are: How do these two definitions relate? What differences are there between QC and QM? Should I learn QM before venturing into QC?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The formulation of "Postulate 1" in the linked pdf is misleading, to say the least. At any given time, the square of the absolute value of the wave function $\psi$ is a probability density. It is not a probability density for integration over space and time.

Comment: @MaoWao As someone who doesn't have a background in QM I would appreciate it if you would point me towards a correct formulation of "Postulate 1".

Comment: @ClassyPies The [Wikipedia formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_formulation_of_quantum_mechanics#Postulates_of_quantum_mechanics) looks good to me

Comment: @BenGrossmann Wikipedia's formulation looks similar to what Scherer presents. However compare that to those found [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html), [here](https://www.ugr.es/~jillana/Docencia/QM/t2.pdf), and [here](https://web.mit.edu/8.05/handouts/jaffe1.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not strictly necessary to learn quantum mechanics (QM) as a prerequisite to quantum computing (QC), since QC questions can be framed purely in terms of linear algebra; typically about unitary and self-adjoint operators over finite dimensional Hilbert spaces.

[In their full generality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_formulation_of_quantum_mechanics#Postulates_of_quantum_mechanics), the postulates of QM describe systems whose state space could be an arbitrary Hilbert space. However, in practice one tends to consider either finite dimensional Hilbert spaces (essentially $\Bbb C^n$) or the Hilbert space $L^2(\Bbb R^n)$ of square-integrable complex-valued functions over $\Bbb R^n$. In this second case, the state-vector $\psi = \psi(\mathbf r,t)$ (describing the state of the system at a given time $t$) is a square-integrable "wave function" over $\Bbb R^n$, and the relevant inner product is given by
$$
\langle \phi | \psi \rangle  = \int_{\Bbb R^n} \phi^*(\mathbf r,t)\psi(\mathbf r,t)\,d\mathbf r.
$$
If one focuses exclusively on this second case, then it is fine to say that the state-vector is always (within the context of interest) a wave-function of this kind.

Comment: Thank you! Now it makes sense. If I understand correctly, the general definition is modified to suit the specific system, where in one case you deal with qubits over a finite-dimensional Hilbert space, or wavefunctions in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ (in regards to the examples discussed).

Comment: @ClassyPies That's right